# how to check if a vector of non-integers numbers is an arithmetic series in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of non-integers numbers and I want to check if the vector is an arithmetic series. here is my code:

```
x=c(5,8.1,11.2,14.3)
is.sequential <- function(x){
    return (all(diff(x) == diff(x)[1]))
  }
is.sequential(x)
```

but I get **False** for this vector. whats wrong with this code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a floating point value, which needs precision.  We could `round` it

```
is.sequential <- function(x, digits = 1){
       x1 <- round(diff(x), digits)
    return(all(x1 == x1[1]))
  }
```

-testing

```
is.sequential(x, 1)
[1] TRUE
```

---

The issue as we mentioned above, it is the precision

```
> 14.3 - 11.2
[1] 3.1
```

Though, it is printing 3.1, it is not actually 3.1

```
print(14.3 - 11.2, digits = 16)
[1] 3.100000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `all.equal` + `var`  + `diff` like below

```
> all.equal(var(diff(x)), 0)
[1] TRUE
```

or `var` + `diff`

```
> var(diff(x)) < .Machine$double.eps
[1] TRUE
```